# Set model's field via onclick (django)

Tags: javascript, python, django

this is my code:

models.py

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'userProfile/static/img', null=True, blank=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    likes_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'photos'
```

and this is a part of html code that my js code produces

```
<div class="container_card">
    <img class="container_card_image" onclick="..." src="/static/img/1/uploads/img1.jpg">
</div>
```

**I want that when you click on the image, 'likes_count' is incremented without refresh the page (like instagram or like all social network).**

Then, if i use `<a href="{% url 'like' value=user.id %}> <img ...> </a>` and a view defined in this way, it increases the likes_count but is not good because it refesh the page for each click

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<value>\w+)$', views.like, name='like'),
]
```

views.py

```
def like(request, value):
    photo = Photos.objects.get(pk=value)
    photo.likes_count += 1
    photo.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: look for "ajax".

Answer (score 0):

In order to get what you want, you need to use ajax.
For example jquery is really simple and easy to make ajax request and handle the response. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.post( "photo/15/like", function( data ) {
  // here you handle the response.
});
```

IN addition your django view should not redirect you to another page, because this will cause the whole page to refresh. Instead you should use a JsonReponse

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    photo = Photos.objects.get(pk=value)
    photo.likes_count += 1
    photo.save()
    return JsonResponse({'action': 'success'}, safe=False)
```

More advance you can use a whole framework which handle json responses like http://www.django-rest-framework.org/, and for writing less code use some of the class based views http://www.cdrf.co/